# Attempting to make a Cross Domain AJAX request to a Server I don't own

Tags: jquery, ajax, server, cross-browser

I'm aware that `javascript` programs running in a browser are bound to the `same-origin` policy which prevents them from requesting services from a server that is on a different domain. What I've gathered from that is that lets say a script on `www.mysite.com` could not request a service from `www.myothersite.com` or even `mysite.com`.

If I run the following code from `www.mysite.com`:

```
var link = "https://www.myothersite.com/jobs-feed.xml";
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: link,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(text){
              alert(text);
      }
})
```

It will result in this error appearing in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
www.myothersite.com/jobs-feed.xml. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'www.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've read that there is a number of ways to prevent this error and make a `cross domain AJAX` request successfully.

1. `JSONP` - This requires the data being returned in `JSON` format but otherwise it will allow JS programs running in browsers to request data from another server in a different domain. Something that is usually prohibited because of the `same-origin policy.`
2. `Cross Origin Request` - 
   Makes use of `HTTP headers` to allow for a `cross-domain` ajax request.  It requires CORs enabled Browser and Server.

Now here is my question, If I'd like to go with a `COR` request and I don't have access to the server to enable it for COR's what should I do? Should I contact the server admin and ask them to allow me to connect? I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Computer Networking and Servers, it's definitely not my strong point.

But from what I've gathered the error above is usually an issue with the server not allowing the requesting domain access to the data? Is that correct?

If so how can I overcome this? ideally, `JSONP` would be a desired option but the data is not in `JSON` format, in my case it's `XML`.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've been looking around at numerous links online and trying to get my head around `CORs` and `cross domain ajax requests`. They've definitely helped me to realize what is going wrong, but I am unsure about how I might go about enabling COR's.

If this is more of a question for `SO` I apologize, I'm more looking for the opinions of others in the programming community.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do:

1. Contact the 3rd party site, and ask if they could include you in
   their CORS policy, if not then
2. Make sure there's no JSONP or similar "public access" point to use, if not then
3. Use a CORS proxy (There's quite a few out there: https://www.google.dk/search?q=free+cors+proxy&oq=free+cor - But do know that you now trust the CORS provider to be the middleman of all information), if your information is too sensitive for this then
4. Build or install your own CORS proxy that you trust

Comment: That's a very helpful answer, thank you. I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you can't take advantage of someone else's AJAX services unless they explicitly give you permission.

There may be all sorts of sensitive information that could be exposed as a result.

My browser protects me from this by enforcing cross-origin policies.

Of course, I could defeat this by modifying my browser to ignore cross-origin concerns. But then I'm just hacking myself.

Comment: I'm not taking advantage of anyone elses services, That's why I'm saying, the server I'm requesting information from provides an `XML feed` of data that should be available for me to use as I pay a license fee to have an account provided with them.  I'm not looking to exploit a service or hack a browser

Comment: Alright. Well, as part of the fee that you pay, they will need to configure their servers to grant your domain permission to use those services. You should probably update your question to be explicit about the fact you are in a contractual relationship with the owner of the other server.